# Collision detection in seemingly random locations

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sdl

I have a square that moves around with user input and should return to top left of screen when it collides with one of the rectangles on the screen. It works fine when the the rectangles are not moving; however, whenever the rectangles oscillate up and down, the square will randomly return to the top left of the screen as if it collided with a rectangle. What is even more strange is, it only does it on the right sides of the rectangles.

I've been trying to figure this out for forever and have finally turned here for help, please do! Its c++ and SDL.

Here is the code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image/SDL_image.h"
#include <string>


const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;
const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 20;

const int SQUARE_WIDTH = 20;
const int SQUARE_HEIGHT = 20;

SDL_Surface *square = NULL;

SDL_Surface *background = NULL;
SDL_Surface * message = NULL;

SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;

SDL_Event event;
SDL_Rect wall;
SDL_Rect wall2;
int wallVel = 5;

class Square 
{
    private:
        SDL_Rect box;
        int xVel, yVel;
    public:
        Square();
        void handle_input();
        void move();
        void show();
};

class Timer
{
    private:
        int startTicks;
        int pausedTicks;
        bool paused;
        bool started;
    public:
        Timer();
        void start();
        void stop();
        void pause ();
        void unpause();

        int get_ticks();
        bool is_started ();
        bool is_paused();
};

SDL_Surface * load_image (std::string filename)
{
    SDL_Surface * loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface * optimizedImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = IMG_Load (filename.c_str());
    if (loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat (loadedImage);
        SDL_FreeSurface (loadedImage);

        if (optimizedImage != NULL)
        {
            SDL_SetColorKey (optimizedImage, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, SDL_MapRGB (optimizedImage -> format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        }
    }

    return optimizedImage;
}

void apply_surface (int x, int y, SDL_Surface * source, SDL_Surface * destination, SDL_Rect * clip = NULL)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface (source, clip, destination, &offset);
}

bool check_collision (SDL_Rect A, SDL_Rect B)
{
    int leftA, leftB;
    int rightA, rightB;
    int topA, topB;
    int bottomA, bottomB;

    leftA = A.x;
    rightA = A.x + A.w;
    topA = A.y;
    bottomA = A.y + A.h;

    leftB = B.x;
    rightB = B.x + B.y;
    topB = B.y;
    bottomB = B.y + B.h;

    if ((bottomA >= topB) && (topA <= bottomB))
    {
        if ((rightA >= leftB) && (leftA <= rightB))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

bool init()
{
    if (SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE);

        if (screen == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption ("Move the square", NULL);

    return true;
}

bool load_files()
{
    square = load_image ("SDL Directory/square.bmp");

    if (square == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void clean_up ()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface (square);
    SDL_Quit ();
}

Square::Square()
{
    box.x = 0;
    box.y = 0;

    box.w = SQUARE_WIDTH;
    box.h = SQUARE_HEIGHT;

    xVel = 0;
    yVel = 0;
}

void Square::handle_input()
{
    if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_UP: yVel -= SQUARE_HEIGHT / 2; break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: yVel += SQUARE_HEIGHT /2; break;
            case SDLK_LEFT: xVel -= SQUARE_WIDTH/2; break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: xVel += SQUARE_WIDTH/2; break;
        }
    }
    else if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
    {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_UP: yVel += SQUARE_HEIGHT / 2; break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: yVel -= SQUARE_HEIGHT /2; break;
            case SDLK_LEFT: xVel += SQUARE_WIDTH/2; break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: xVel -= SQUARE_WIDTH/2; break;
        }
    }
}

void Square::move()
{
    box.x += xVel;

    if (box.x <0)
    {
        box.x = 0;
    }
    if (box.x+SQUARE_WIDTH > SCREEN_WIDTH)
    {
        box.x = SCREEN_WIDTH-SQUARE_WIDTH;
    }

    box.y += yVel;

    if (box.y <0)
    {
        box.y = 0;
    }
    if (box.y + SQUARE_HEIGHT > SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    {
        box.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT-SQUARE_HEIGHT;
    }
    if (check_collision (box, wall))
    {
        box.x = 0;
        box.y = 0;
    }
    if (check_collision (box, wall2))
    {
        box.x = 0;
        box.y = 0;
    }
}

void Square::show()
{
    apply_surface (box.x, box.y, square, screen);
}

void wall_move()
{
    wall2.y += wallVel;
    wall.y += wallVel;
    if (wall.y <= 0)  
    {
        wallVel = 5;
    }
    if (wall.y+wall.h >= SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    {
        wallVel = -5;
    }

}

Timer::Timer ()
{
    startTicks = 0;
    pausedTicks = 0;
    paused = false;
    started = false;
}

void Timer::start()
{
    started = true;
    paused = false;
    startTicks = SDL_GetTicks();
}
void Timer::stop()
{
    started = false;
    paused = false;
}

void Timer::pause()
{
    if ((started == true) && (paused == false))
    {
        paused = true;
        pausedTicks = SDL_GetTicks() - startTicks;
    }
}

void Timer::unpause()
{
    if (paused == true)
    {
        paused = false;
        startTicks= SDL_GetTicks() - pausedTicks;
        pausedTicks = 0;
    }
}

int Timer::get_ticks()
{
    if (started == true)
    {
        if (paused == true)
        {
            return pausedTicks;
        }
        else
        {
            return SDL_GetTicks() - startTicks;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool Timer::is_started ()
{
    return started;
}

bool Timer::is_paused()
{
    return paused;
}

void game_loop()
{
    bool quit = false;
    Square mySquare;
    Timer fps;
    wall.x = 300;
    wall.y = 40;
    wall.w = 40;
    wall.h = 400;
    wall2.x = 200;
    wall2.y = 40;
    wall2.w = 40;
    wall2.h = 400;

    while (quit == false)
    {
        fps.start();

        while (SDL_PollEvent (&event))
        {
            mySquare.handle_input ();

            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }

        wall_move(); 
        mySquare.move();
        SDL_FillRect (screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB (screen->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        SDL_FillRect (screen, &wall, SDL_MapRGB (screen->format, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77));
        SDL_FillRect (screen, &wall2, SDL_MapRGB (screen->format, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77));
        mySquare.show();

        SDL_Flip (screen);

        if (fps.get_ticks() < 1000/FRAMES_PER_SECOND)
        {
            SDL_Delay ((1000/ FRAMES_PER_SECOND) - fps.get_ticks());
        }
    }
}


int main ( int argc, char* args[])
{

    if (init () == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (load_files () == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    game_loop();

    clean_up();

    return 0;
}
```

If I move my square right here it will collide and return to top left no problem.
!([http://imgur.com/49Ec0nw](https://imgur.com/49Ec0nw))

From here, though, when I move down only a few more pixels it will return to top left as if it collided with a rectangle.
!([http://imgur.com/XiylEXJ](https://imgur.com/XiylEXJ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "bool check_collision (SDL_Rect A, SDL_Rect B) {}" , you have the following:

```
rightB = B.x + B.y;
```

I think you meant to put this:

```
rightB = B.x + B.w;
```

Although I'm not sure I completely understand how you're reproducing the issue, see if that helps.

Comment: Oh my gosh I feel dumb, that did it haha!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the detection be

```
if ((bottomA <= topB) && (topA >= bottomB))
{
    if ((rightA >= leftB) && (leftA <= rightB))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

not

```
if ((bottomA >= topB) && (topA <= bottomB))
{
    if ((rightA >= leftB) && (leftA <= rightB))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

(Inverted >= and <= in first if statement)

Comment: I check to see if they overlap, not if they are outside of each other. In this case if the bottom, the y, moves and overlaps the top of the other rectangle. Im closing the question though because I had a dumb error in the variables.